# Do factory printed CD music and DVD movies contain these organic dyes?

Tags: archiving

Since, CD-R and DVD-R contain organic dyes in them which then causes them to degrade in time. I wanted to know if music CDs / movie DVDs that you buy in retail stores contain organic dyes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no, manufactured optical discs are made by "pressing", which molds real pits, or imperfections, into a layer that is sandwiched between other layers. The longevity of these pressed discs is much greater than the "burned" discs consumers can produce, though still not "forever".

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thanks for the quick response.